# Why do we need to type '(" + i + ")' instead of just '(i)'

Tags: javascript, xml, dom

Here, while calling a function displayCDinfo(), the syntax used is

```
document.write("<tr onclick='displayCDInfo(" + i + ")'>");
```

where i is the for loop counter. 
However, the function declaration is given as

```
function displayCDInfo(i)
{
... 
}
```

Why do they use displayCDinfo(" + i + ") instead of displayCDinfo(i) while calling the function? The code doesn't work when the "+ +" is removed.

Comment: Well, what difference do you see between what `document.write` outputs in each case?

Answer (score 5):

The `+` operator is joining the variable's value to the string. Otherwise you are sending the letter `i` instead of what `i` contains.

Answer (score 0):

It's all about the quotes. In the first instance, it's escaping the string to allow `i` to be sent as a variable instead of a character